# hive 0.14 acid enabled table performance issue due to too many delta files

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I have created table with ACID properties in hive 0.14.

My sample create table script:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_test (id STRING, link STRING, came_from STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (datestamp STRING) CLUSTERED BY (id) INTO 56 BUCKETS STORED AS ORC;
```

Whenever I do an update/insert/delete it is creating one delta file under each partition directory in hdfs
Like below. Currently in the warehouse dir we have more than 10 delta files, but as per the hive-site.xml settings
Minor compaction should happen for every 10 delta files creation and we should not have more than 10 delta files under each 
Partition dir. But currently I can see more than 10 delta files (in fact 15) under each partition dir.

```
/usr/hive/warehouse/db_path/sample_test/datestamp=2015-06-13/delta_000001_000001/bucket_0000_0000
/usr/hive/warehouse/db_path/sample_test/datestamp=2015-06-13/delta_000001_000001/bucket_0001_0001

/usr/hive/warehouse/db_path/sample_test/datestamp=2015-06-13/delta_000001_000001/bucket_0055_0055

/usr/hive/warehouse/db_path/sample_test/datestamp=2015-06-13/delta_000015_000015/bucket_0000_0000
```

So when I do a select count(*) on this table sample_test it is running for more than 250 secs to give the result.
I have only 150 records in this table (sample_test).

I tried doing a manual compaction using below command but still no improvement and delta files count remains the same.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename [PARTITION (partition_key='partition_value' [,...])] COMPACT 'compaction_type'
```

But when I create table from existing table like below. Only the base files are getting copied into ne table location (no delta files) and my select count(*) on the new table sample_test2 is very fast (less than a second to give the count of 150).

```
Create table sample_test2 select * from sample_test;
```

My hive-site.xml values are like below:

```
hive.compactor.worker.timeout   86400 
hive.compactor.check.interval   300 
hive.compactor.delta.num.threshold  10L
hive.compactor.delta.pct.threshold  0.1f 
hive.compactor.abortedtxn.threshold 1
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.